# Model class generation disabled: disabled in project (CoreML Code Generation Language set to "none"

Tags: xcode, coreml, mlmodel

I've downloaded this project from apple's developers' website: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/recognizing_objects_in_live_capture

But I'm getting this error(?) under the Model Class when I inspect the mlmodel object. Is there anything to do there?

Answer (score 5):

Set the "CoreML Code Generation Language" setting to something else than “none”. You can do this in the build settings for your project / target.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Matthijs Hollemans answer, and for a better performance you need to

set the "CoreML Code Generation Language" setting to Automatic rather than none.

As a more visual explanation for it 
please check Next Photo:

[image]